# Why scroll to top not working when I use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a popup that is dynamically loading content and using `overflow: auto` to maintain the popup size and in turn make it scrollable. I have a link at the bottom currently using anchors to scroll to the top of the div. Unfortunately it is also forcing the page to scroll down to that point as well as scroll to the top of that div.

I am trying to prevent the page from scrolling and only scroll to the top of the div. I have tried numerous scenarios of scroll to top:

```
$('#id').scrollTop(0);
```

as well as

```
$('#id').animate({
   scrollTop: 0
}, 'slow');
```

Unfortunately this is doing nothing. I am not getting any errors. I have attempted to try it in a console and not attached to any click event and it does nothing and just prints the id to the console that I am targeting.

Here is the link to the actual production version of this page. If you click the link for privacy policy, terms or learn more and then hit any of the back to top links you will see what the issue is.

[Here is the site](https://carnet.vw.com/portal/en/owners/carnet?p_p_id=vwdbsappfactoryappsconnectedservicesconnectedcar_WAR_vwdbsappfactoryappsconnectedservicesconnectedcarportlet_INSTANCE_Jz5e&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_vwdbsappfactoryappsconnectedservicesconnectedcar_WAR_vwdbsappfactoryappsconnectedservicesconnectedcarportlet_INSTANCE_Jz5e_action=view#contenttop)

Comment: Can you please explain a little better what are you trying to do? Site and functionality looks good to me.

Comment: Your production site is at a `vw.com` sub-domain?

Comment: BTW, if I fix the problem I don't want the points, just a VW Phaeton :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i used

```
$( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 0 );
```

Comment: This worked though I had to add a timing to it to of 500.  Thanks.  Right now instead of html, body i am doing it to the container of the popup to prevent the body from scrolling.  once again appreciate the answer.  Now to see which way they want.  body to scroll to top or purely  just the content. =)